# Equivalence class checking my answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please check my answer and tell me if im thinking in proper way.

I have to find all equivalence classes in equivalence relation $\mathcal R$ in set
$A = (k \in \Bbb Z: -230\le k \le 2003)$ defined as follows:

$m\mathcal R l \iff m^2 = l^2$ for $m,l \in \Bbb Z$

Equivalence class will look as follows: $[m]$ = {$l \in A: m\mathcal R l$}

Let's take a look numbers in this set. First of all I'm checking negative number:

$[-230]$ = {$\emptyset$} because here doesn't exist number such that any number can be power to negative number. It's contradiction.

$[0]$ = {$0$} I think that is easy and obvious.

Let's take positive number for example:

$[1]$ = {$-1,1$} because if we want have result 1, we can increase the positive and negative number (I mean $(-1)^2$ = $1$ and $1^1$ = $1$ ).

Summing up all possible equivalence classes we get 2004, because we have 2004 representative of class (from 0 to 2003).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the definition of $\mathcal{R}$.  If it's true that $[-230] = \emptyset$, then $\mathcal{R}$ is not an equivalence relation.  Also, if $[1] = \{-1,1\}$, then $[-1] = \{-1,1\}$, too.

Comment: You're right about $[1] = $[-1] = $\{1,-1\}$ and $[0]$. The argument for $[1]$ should show you why you are wrong about $[-230]$. What about $[231]$?

Comment: Oh yes i see now! $[231]$ = {$231$}. So, $[-230]$ = {$230$}. Now there is something like $[-230]=[230]$ and answer is still the same?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{R}$ reflexive or not?

Comment: Yes it must be reflexive, if its equivalence relation. So $[-230] = $ {$-230,230$} , because of reflexivity ( for example reflexive for -230 its $m \mathcal R m \iff (-230)^2 = (-230)^2 $.

Comment: Now you're getting there!